# How to fix error on writing data into a pgm file

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

How to fix error when try to convert frame into grayscale?

Error message: cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:259: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::CvtHelper,struct cv::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)' > Invalid number of channels in input image: > 'VScn::contains(scn)' > where > 'scn' is 1

```
class OpenCVCapture(object):
def __init__(self, device_id=0):
    """Create an OpenCV capture object associated with the provided webcam
    device ID.
    """
    # Open the camera.
    self._camera = cv2.VideoCapture(device_id)
    if not self._camera.isOpened():
        self._camera.open()
    # Start a thread to continuously capture frames.
    # This must be done because different layers of buffering in the webcam
    # and OS drivers will cause you to retrieve old frames if they aren't 
    # continuously read.
    self._capture_frame = None
    # Use a lock to prevent access concurrent access to the camera.
    self._capture_lock = threading.Lock()
    self._capture_thread = threading.Thread(target=self._grab_frames)
    self._capture_thread.daemon = True
    self._capture_thread.start()

def _grab_frames(self):
    while True:
        retval, frame = self._camera.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        with self._capture_lock:
            self._capture_frame = None
            if retval:
                self._capture_frame = frame
        time.sleep(1.0/CAPTURE_HZ)

def read(self):
    """Read a single frame from the camera and return the data as an OpenCV
    image (which is a numpy array).
    """
    frame = None
    with self._capture_lock:
        frame = self._capture_frame

    # If there are problems, keep retrying until an image can be read.
    while frame is None:
        time.sleep(0)
        with self._capture_lock:
            frame = self._capture_frame
    # Save captured image for debugging.
    cv2.imwrite(config.DEBUG_IMAGE, frame)
    # Return the capture image data.
    return frame
```

Comment: Please, provide `frame.shape` and `frame.dtype`

Comment: You might want to proof-read your post (especially title) -- `imwrite` (as the name would suggest) isn't used for **reading**... | Also add a proper [mcve] -- right now you claim you "feed in grayscale image"... but how do we know that's actually the case?

Comment: @DanMašek i added in code which i turn the image frame into grayscale, thanks for the correction

Comment: @Berriel the shape is (480, 640, 3) and dtype uint8

Comment: Given that the 3rd value of shape (the number of channels) is 3, it's definitely not a grayscale image at that point... which seems rather odd given that code.

Comment: @DanMašek sorry i print out the value before converting, the real value should be (480,640)

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if this is a synchronization issue... what happens if you make a copy of the frame (`frame = self._capture_frame.copy()`)?

Comment: Please don't put code and error messages in comments- they are unformatted and hard to read. Rather, click `edit` under your question and keep the entire question in the question area where everyone can see it without scrambling through loads of comments. Thank you.

Comment: updated the problem of converting frame to grayscale

Comment: Move the `cvtColor` down until after you've verified that `retval` doesn't indicate an error. Some webcams have a warmup period that will fail the first few attempts to snag a frame.